# Issue with kotlin properties after updating android studio artic fix 2020.3.1 patch 2

Tags: arrays, string, android-studio, kotlin, properties

[Error while sorting applied and check string empty or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNhxC.png)

I have recently update my android studio into **artic fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2**, and than suddenly faced multiple error like showing in image in general pre define properties like short function, toInt(), toLong(), uppercase(), lowercase(), check string is empty or not etc. Please let me know if someone will help me for resolving this things in my code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community It solved now, after I have get latest version Android studio.